# Происхождение слов

Tags: орфография

Что надо знать о происхождении слов "неделя",  "земляника" и "памятник" чтобы не ошибиться в их написании?

Answer (score 2):

Что неделя произошла от сочетания "не делать" (первоначально так называли, только воскресенье). Земляника  - от слова "земля", а памятник - от "память". Соответственно для проверки безударных гласных, можно использовать производные этих слов.